# "Paypal Login button" doesn't work in Sandbox

Tags: html, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm building a site where users can login with [Paypal login](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/log-in-with-paypal/integrate/). Going live requires approval form Paypal so I'm testing the sandbox environment. I'm just redirecting the user to the Paypal login page as instructed in the docs.

```js
const CLIENT_ID = "MY_CLIENT_ID"
const BASE_URL = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/connect"
const SCOPES = "openid email"
const REDIRECT_URL = encodeURIComponent("https://my.webiste.com")
const URL = `${BASE_URL}?flowEntry=static&client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&scope=${SCOPES}&redirect_uri=${REDIRECT_URL}&state=123456`

<div >
  <button>
    <a href={URL}>Login with Paypal</a>
  </button>
</div>
```

The issue I'm encountering is that I can't login with any credentials/accounts I have.

**What I have tried**

1. Using the same account that is connected to my credentials above. (email in screenshot changed for privacy reasons) This gives the the following error:

[image]

2. Using a ready made sandbox account that can be found in the [Paypal Developer Portal](https://developer.paypal.com/dashboard/accounts/) but I get the same error. The ready made sanbox accounts look something like this `sb-sk9y4897349@business.example.com`

What am I missing here? What account should I be using to test the sandbox version of "Login with Paypal" functionality? I don't think there is an issue with my URL since it actually redirects me to the Paypal OAuth login page.

Comment: what is the actual URL

Comment: @PrestonPHX I edited the code now to show how the URL is constructed

Comment: actual URL with actual sandbox values

Comment: For some reason it works now, maybe I had to wait for some time for redirect_urls to be set or something. But here is the [URL] (https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/connect?flowEntry=static&client_id=AQ6jBMzUhINWwDDe1T_fnkhA89hEM6M9DsbGwNPUHohwr0qNL8n5CtX3IxThnFw8sLzP9mxfdxHZDXIi&scope=openid email https://uri.paypal.com/services/paypalattributes https://uri.paypal.com/services/paypalattributes&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fe9ce-90-225-198-55.ngrok-free.app%2Fintegrations&state=123456)

Comment: It does take 3-9 hours for changes to the App settings to have an effect, though I didn't expect that issue based on the the error message (usually it's "invalid client_id or redirect uri")